htaccess not allowing access to directory
I'm newbie to using .htaccess.  What I want to do is to granting selected users access to a restricted directory. Everything I've tried results in either a redirection to the website's homepage or an "Internal Server Error" message.
In the name/password form (a.php), if I set action to "protected/index.php"  I get the server error message. If I set the action to "protected/" the error_redirect file takes me to the homepage.
In the protected directory, index.php is a simple php file with a single echo line and does work outside the directory.
In the htpasswd file I list the username and the md5 hash of the user's password.  This list is generated from a database.  The username and passwords are correct.
In the name/password file (a.php), the password that the user enters is md5 encrypted and the encryption does match that of the htpasswd file and database.
The htpasswd file contains this line: joe:098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
The index.php file contains this line:  "you are in"
I'm missing something somewhere but do not know what.
Test url:  https://wcart.net/a/a.php  ----  username='joe' and password='test'.
The code for  the form file (a.php) is:
     <h3>Login </h3>
     <form method="POST">
          <label for="user">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="user" name="username" required>
          <p>
          <label for="psw">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="psw" name="password" required>
          <p>
          <button type="submit" name="login" >Login</button>
          <br>
     </form>
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['login'])){
          $username=$_POST['username'];
          $password=md5($_POST['password']);
          echo "<p>
               <form method='post' action ='protected/'>
                    <input type='text' name='user' value=$username>
                    <input type='text' name='password' value=$password>
               <p>
               time to go<p>
               <button type='submit' name='go' >go</button>
               ";
     }
     ?>


Aaaaand what's inside of .htaccess? I mean, you are asking us about possible problems in this file but for some reason hide its contents from us.

But your main problem is attempt to use PHP. You cannot use PHP to protect a directory. When using .htaccess to protect a directory, everything is done by Apache and your browser. Neither PHP not HTML form can be involved here. The password will be requested by the browser directly.

I guess you could set the action of the form to something like https://user:password@example.com/protected for the server to pick up the credentials from the URL Would be nice to see the content of the actual .htaccess file.

@Cyclonecode afaik, you cannot

@YourCommonSense - Just tried here on Apache 2.4 and it works without any problem. Of course you still need to have the correct directives in your .htaccess and a password file for this to work.
